# Where are these BIONICLE sets?

Tags: shopping, bionicle

I'm from Norway and I wonder why BIONICLE sets creature of jungle and stone are nowhere to be found around here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you say "are nowhere to be found around here" - perhaps you mean Brick & Mortar stores? Both these BIONICLE sets are available from the Norwegian shop.lego.com site:

[image]